# How to turn a string into a list of list?

Tags: python-3.x, string, split

I would like to turn a string into a list of list by \n, and then split the string in the sublist by whitespace.

Example:-

```
('We are champion\n We won the game\n')
```

Result that desired one:-

```
[['We', 'are', 'champion'], ['We', 'won', 'the', 'game']]
```

I somehow get confused of the function split and find out that I cannot use split in a sublist.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to ask a good question that will lead to good answers. In the meantime, can you update your question and show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```py
text = 'We are champion\n We won the game\n'

arr = []

for sentence in text.split('\n'):
    sentence = sentence.strip()

    if sentence:
        arr.append(sentence.split(' '))

print(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still got sublist like [''] after implement the code. Do you know how to get rid of it? Thanks:)

Comment: Thanks for your help. So the if sentence help us get rid of the empty list right?

Comment: @Alex Yep!  An empty string is considered `False` in Python. Essentially we are saying if the list of words is empty, do not add it to the `arr` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splitlines` to split string by the new line. then loop it to `split` into words and append to the result's `array`.

Tips: You can use `strip` to trim the empty space of the string before perform the split.

```
txt = "We are champion\n We won the game\n"

xs = txt.strip().splitlines()

result = [];

for x in xs:
  result.append(x.split())

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me the splitlines function. But this result will contain empty sublist in the list at the place will \n exists. Do you know how to get rid of that?

Comment: I already update the answer with add the strip feature to remove empty space.